# Ultisnips python interpolation snippet, extracting number from filename

Tags: python, vim, ultisnips

I am trying to make a snippet that will help me choose the right revision
number for migration, by reading all migration files from
`application/migrations`.

What I managed to do myself is that my filenames are being filtered while I am
typing, and when only one match left insert its revision number at the cursor
position (which are first 14 chars of filename always).

The problem is that when I hit TAB to select, I am also left with what I have
typed so far to search for that revision number, meaning something like this
`remo20160812110447`.

Question is, how to get rid of that `remo` in this case!?

NOTE: Example uses hardcoded values, for easier testing, those will be later
replaced by `# lst = os.listdir('application/migrations')` line.

Also an added bonus effect would be to present those `20160710171947` values as
human readable date format while choosing, but after hitting TAB insert their
original source version.

```
global !p
import datetime
def complete(t, opts):
if t:
    opts = [ m for m in opts if t in m ]
if len(opts) == 1:
    return opts[0][:14]
return "(" + '|'.join(opts) + ')'
endglobal

snippet cimigration "Inserts desired migration number, obtained via filenames"
$1`!p import os
# lst = os.listdir('application/migrations')
lst = [
    '20160710171947_create.php',
    '20160810112347_delete.php',
    '20160812110447_remove.php'
]
snip.rv = complete(t[1], lst)`
endsnippet
```

Comment: I would be more than happy to know the reason, why the person `x` down-voted this question. The question isn't about python itself, as that would be easily solved than, but the plugin behavior in this case.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but I'd like to argue two things: You might want to hit the `flag` button an ask a moderator to move the question to [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com/), more people may be able to help there.  Also, I never used ultisnips, but I'd argue this is not too hard to write in pure vimscript.  You can use `split(globpath('application/migrations', '*.php'))` to get a list and then `viwc` once you hit `<tab>`.

Comment: the point is filtering results while typing, thus narrowing search results, not obtaining plain list of files

Answer (score 2):

This can definitely be performed in pure vimscript.

Here is a working prototype.  It does work but has some issues with portability: global variables, reliance on `iskeyword` and uses two keybindings instead of one.  But it was put together in an hour or so:

```
set iskeyword=@,48-57,_,-,.,192-255
let g:wordidx = 0
let g:word = ''
let g:match = 0
function! Suggest()
  let l:glob = globpath('application/migrations', '*.php')
  let l:files = map(split(l:glob), 'fnamemodify(v:val, ":t")')
  let l:char = getline('.')[col('.')-1]
  let l:word = ''
  let l:suggestions = []
  if l:char =~# '[a-zA-Z0-9_]'
    if g:word ==# ''
      let g:word = expand('<cword>')
      let g:match = matchadd('ErrorMsg', g:word)
    endif
    let l:word = g:word
    "let l:reg = '^' . l:word
    let l:suggestions = filter(l:files, 'v:val =~ l:word')
    if !empty(l:suggestions)
      call add(l:suggestions, l:word)
      "echo l:suggestions
      let l:change = l:suggestions[g:wordidx]
      let g:wordidx = (g:wordidx + 1) % len(l:suggestions)
      "echo g:wordidx + 10
      execute "normal! mqviwc" . l:change . "\<esc>`q"
    endif
  endif
  "echo [l:word, l:suggestions]
endfunction

function! SuggestClear()
  call matchdelete(g:match)
  let g:wordidx = 0
  let g:word = ''
  let g:match = 0
endfunction

nnoremap <leader><tab> :call Suggest()<cr>
nnoremap <leader><cr>  :call SuggestClear()<cr>
```

Adding this to your `~/.vimrc` will allow you to steps through search matches with `<leader><tab>`.  It will highlight the part that is being matched, to drop the highlight you need to type `<leader><cr>`.

You should always drop the highlight after use because the original search word is kept internally until you destroy it.  Using `<leader><tab>` before clearing the match will substitute for the suggestions from the previous match.

Screencast (my leader is `-`):

[image]

---

If you have more vim questions join the [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) subsection of the website.  You can probably get better answers there.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using `post-expand-actions`: https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/master/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L1602